# Unable to execute Ajax call to c# method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

Im trying to call a c# method on select changed event of a dropdown list,The select change event triggers but the ajax does not work

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {


              $('body').delegate('#drpselect1', 'change', function () {
                  var groupname = $("#drpselect1 option:selected").text();
                  alert(groupname);
                  $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      url: "sample.aspx/getdata",
                      dataType: "json",
                      {"text":groupname},
                      success: function () {
                         alert("works");
                          // window.location.href = "ClubCreation.aspx";
                      },
                      Error: function () {
                          alert('error');
                      }
                  });
             /*     $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      url: "sample.aspx/getdata",
                        data:{"text":groupname}
                                          dataType: "json",
                      success: function () {
                          alert('Successfully Saved');
                          //window.location.href = "ClubCreation.aspx";
                      },
                      Error: function () {
                      }


    });*/

          });


      });




</script>
```

c# method

```
[WebMethod]
     public static void getdata(String text)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
```

Comment: It's `error: function(...)` not `Error: function(...)` and `alert('error')` isn't that helpful either. Check the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) and use the supplied parameters of the error handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

check this line

```
                      data:'{"text":"'+groupname+'"}',//put "data:"
```

now,

```
$.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      url: "sample.aspx/getdata",
                      dataType: "json",
                      data:'{"text":"'+groupname+'"}',//put "data:"
                      success: function () {
                         alert("works");
                          // window.location.href = "ClubCreation.aspx";
                      },
                      Error: function () {
                          alert('error');
                      }
                  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to decorate getdata method with 
`[WebMethod]` attribute. 
In your c# code `[WebMethod]` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Probabky you missing attributes:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()] 
public static void getdata(String text)
```

Look here for more informations: [Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Comment: sorry forgot to add that in question.I had used webmethod